# Call the Windows explorer to open files in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, class, explorer

I develop a graphic program with Qt and I have a problem about opening files. I created a button to exit the program and an other to select a file among many files in a specific folder. Is it possible to call the Windows explorer to select the destination of my file I want to open with Qt ?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "_call the Windows explorer to select the destination of my file_"? Would you like to show the folder of the file in Windows Explorer? You can do that with QDesktopServices.

Comment: You need a standard Windows folder/file choose dialog, not the Explorer. Look at `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`.

Comment: @ilotXXI, Thank you, that's what I was searching !